# Mysql and PHP frequency based on time

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project to graph frequency over a time period. The server currently stores all the data I need apart from the count as this will change over time. I am pulling all of the data that I need using the following code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1",xxx,xxx);
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("tweets", $con);
$results = array();

$result = mysql_query("SELECT company, time FROM data WHERE company = 'AAPL'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $results[] = $row;
}

$results = json_encode($results);
mysql_close($con);
echo $results;
?>
```

When returned I have an array that contains all of the company names and times. how would I go about counting the frequency within a time frame, for example the frequency in the past 24 hours and then a separate value for the previous 24 hours?

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You just loop through the data, the exact code depends on the format of the time and the format of the result required. You could do something like this :

```
$summary =array();
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $day = substring($result['time'], 0, 10);
    if(isset($summary[$day])){
        $summary[$day]++;
    } else {
        $summary[$day] = 1;
    }
}
```

Write the function getDay() according to the format of the time.

Comment: I understand the basics of what you are saying, you said it depends on the format? do you have a link I can look at to explain that?

Comment: Basically the question is if time is in unix timestamp format or as datetime 'Y-m-d H:i:s'.

Comment: It is in a format of Y-M-D / H-M-S. Unsure as to what the get day function is meant to do.

Comment: You said you want to count the frequencies per day. 'Y-M-D / H-M-S' is not a valid format. I really hope it is 'Y-m-d H:i:s'. But never mind: the function should just return an identifier of the period during which you count the occurrences. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your date/time values are stored as MySQL datetime (and for your sake I hope they are) then the solution is trivial.  Select records within a certain time period and group by company, e.g.

```
SELECT 
    `company`, COUNT(`company`) AS total 
FROM 
    `data` 
WHERE 
    `time` >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
GROUP BY 
    company
```

In this example I use MySQL to compute the 24 hour period, but you could just as easily have PHP compute an exact time/date.

If you want a pure PHP solution, then start by storing your times grouped by companies in a multidimensional array.  Convert your times from your DB format to Unix time.  In my example I use strtotime(); if your db times are in a funky format then you'll need to do something else to convert them.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT company, time FROM data");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $results[$row['company']] = strtotime($row['time']);
}
```

Then simply loop the array and evaluate.

```
// 24 hours before now
$start = time() - ( 24*60*60);
$lastTwentyFourHours = array();
foreach ( $results as $company => $times ) {
    if ( !isset($lastTwentyFourHours[$company]) ) {
        $lastTwentyFourHours[$company] = 0;
    }
    foreach ( $times as $time ) {
        if ( $time >= $start ) {
            $lastTwentyFourHours[$company]++;
        }
    }
}
print_r($lastTwentyFourHours);
```